# Selenium click on button by class name

Tags: python, selenium

Hi I am new at using selenium and I am automating a certain process for my work. I have successfully been able to fill in forms and click on several buttons but when verifying my MFA, the button to verify doesn't work.

HTML for button:

```
<button class = "btn blue trustdevice trustbtn" onclick="updateTrustDevice(true)"> 
<span class ="loadwithbtn" style="display: none;"></span> 
<span class "waittext">Trust</span> 
</button>
```

My code:

```
browser.find_element_by_class_name("btn blue trustdevice trustbtn").click()
```

I receive this error
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element:
Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".btn blue
trustdevice trustbtn"}

I also tried

```
elements = browser.find_element_by_class_name("btn blue trustdevice trustbtn")
for e in elements:
e.click()
```

but received the same error. Please let me know if any more info is required!

EDIT:

```
button = browser.find_element_by_class_name("btn blue trustdevice trustbtn")
```

gives me the same error message as well.

Comment: Is it possible that there's a delay before the button HTML is rendered that way? If so, you can use an explicit wait to wait until the element shows up.

Comment: @shynjax287 I don't believe so. I was able to immediately click it with my mouse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`find_element_by_class_name`() only accept single classname. Instead use `css selector.`

Induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `element_to_be_clickable`()

You can use either of locator.

**Css Selector:**

```
WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".btn.blue.trustdevice.trustbtn"))).click()
```

OR

**Xpath:**

```
WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[./span[text()='Trust']]"))).click()
```

You need to import below libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a common issue that people tend to forget that you have to add some `time.sleep()` between your clicks to let the page load. So i would suggest to add:

```
import time

# action

time.sleep(5) #wait 5 seconds

# next action
```

Also you can use seleniums [waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading")
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "myDynamicElement"))
    )
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: When I try button = browser.find_element_by_class_name("btn blue trustdevice trustbtn") it also gives me the same error. I don't believe it is due to the page loading.